# What is request.postData in stack trace

Tags: java, web-services, security, request

My application uses a web service to authenticate. After the correct authentication user is redirected to the dashboard.

When we designed the application, we had strong agreement to never send any data unless users is authenticated.

However, when I debug through the authentication algorithms, I noticed that the request.postData has array of data. This is so confusing. I checked the web-service too. it doesn't provide any data in the process of authentication.

what is exactly request.postData?

what information do you guys need to give  a hint?

Answer (score 1):

`postData` is the message body of a [`POST` request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)).

An example<sup>[1](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSImportExport/latest/DG/SamplePOSTRequest.html)</sup> HTTP POST request is as follows:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8
host: https://importexport.amazonaws.com
content-length:207

Action=GetStatus&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&JobId=JOBID&SignatureVersion=2&Version=2014-12-18&Signature=%2FVfkltRBOoSUi1sWxRzN8rw%3D&Timestamp=2014-12-20T22%3A30%3A59.556Z
```

With a POST request, the user can't see the data as it is sent from their browser to the server, unless they use a debugging tools. Whereas, in a GET request the data would be shown in the browser address bar.

For example, if the above was a GET the URL would become:

```
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSImportExport/latest/DG/SamplePOSTRequest.html?Action=GetStatus&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&JobId=JOBID&SignatureVersion=2&Version=2014-12-18&Signature=%2FVfkltRBOoSUi1sWxRzN8rw%3D&Timestamp=2014-12-20T22%3A30%3A59.556Z
```

So if your application authenticates against the web service using POST data (which is likely), request.postData` is the data it has sent.

Comment: Thanks. But why do I get them all as integer values?